# Issue with screen bounds on iOS

Tags: ios, screen, uidatepicker

I'm fairly new with iOS coding so i'm using a few libraries I found on github. I have one that loads up a pop up UIDatePicker and it was working fine until I added code to choose which view to load when the app first launches. Here's all the relevant code I could find. Any help would be appreciated.

From DatePickerDialog:

```
func countScreenSize() -> CGSize {
    var screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
    var screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

    let interfaceOrientaion = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation

    if UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientaion) {
        let tmp = screenWidth
        screenWidth = screenHeight
        screenHeight = tmp
    }

    return CGSizeMake(screenWidth, screenHeight)
}

override init() {
    super.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height))

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "deviceOrientationDidChange:", name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
}
```

And here is the code I added to the app delegate to choose which view to load:

```
if currentUser != nil {

    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    var initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loggedin") as UIViewController

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

} else {

    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    var initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("start") as UIViewController

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: what's the problem ? And what did you expect ?

Comment: @KIDdAe When I click the button that pops up the UIDatePicker it doesn't do anything.  The button does work when I remove the code in my app delegate that chooses a specific view wether a user is logged in or not so i'm assuming that something is conflicting with the pop up date picker I have

Comment: Not clear where this code is. Have you debugged to check what is called and what it does? What are the differences between the working code and the failing code?

Comment: here's the full code I have for the datepickerdialog. Its in its own class file within my project. The code in my application delegate is above.

http://www.filedropper.com/datepickerdialog

Comment: I figured it out. It wasn't working because I had an init RootViewController set.